# How to define TopicPolicy in Cloudformation template for codebuild failure notification

Tags: amazon-web-services, notifications, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-codebuild

I have created the cloudformation template to create **SNS Topic, Subscription, Cloudwatch rule and TopicPolicy** to send mail notification if a codebuild is failed. And When I tried creating, the template is deployed and it created **Topic, Subscription and Cloudwatch rule**, No errors in output. And the notification mail is not being sent if codebuild is failed. I used the below template:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: Creates SNS topic, SNS subscription and Cloudwatch rule for Codebuild Notification
Parameters:
  SubscriptionEndPoint:
    Type: String
    Description: The endpoint that receives notifications.
  SubscriptionProtocol:
    Type: String
    Description: The subscription protocol
    AllowedValues:
    - http
    - https
    - email
    - email-json
    - sms
    - sqs
    - application
    - lambda
    Default: email
Mappings: {}
Conditions: {}
Resources:
  SNSTopic:
    Type: AWS::SNS::Topic
    Properties: {}
  SNSSubscription:
    Type: AWS::SNS::Subscription
    Properties:
      Protocol:
        Ref: SubscriptionProtocol
      Endpoint:
        Ref: SubscriptionEndPoint
      TopicArn:
        Ref: SNSTopic

  SnsPolicy:
    Type: AWS::SNS::TopicPolicy
    Properties: 
      Topics: [!Ref SNSTopic]         
      PolicyDocument: !Sub |
          {
            "Version": "2012-10-17",
            "Id": "__default_policy_ID",
            "Statement": [
              {
                "Sid": "__default_statement_ID",
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Principal": {
                  "AWS": "*"
                },
                "Action": [
                  "SNS:GetTopicAttributes",
                  "SNS:SetTopicAttributes",
                  "SNS:AddPermission",
                  "SNS:RemovePermission",
                  "SNS:DeleteTopic",
                  "SNS:Subscribe",
                  "SNS:ListSubscriptionsByTopic",
                  "SNS:Publish",
                  "SNS:Receive"
                ],
                "Resource": "${SNSTopic}",
                "Condition": {
                  "StringEquals": {
                    "AWS:SourceOwner": "${AWS::AccountId}"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "Sid": "Allow Events",
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Principal": {
                  "Service": "events.amazonaws.com"
                },
                "Action": "sns:Publish",
                "Resource": "${SNSTopic}"
              }
            ]
          }


  CodebuildStateFailureEventRule:
    Type: "AWS::Events::Rule"
    Properties:
      Description: "Rule for sending failure notifications to SNS topic"
      EventPattern:
        source:
          - aws.codebuild
        detail-type:
          - CodeBuild Build State Change
        detail:
          project-name:
            - TestCodeBuildProject
          build-status:
            - FAILED
      State: "ENABLED"
      Targets:
       - Arn: !Ref SNSTopic
         Id: CodeBuildNotificationTest
         InputTransformer:
            InputPathsMap:
              build-id: "$.detail.build-id"
              project-name: "$.detail.project-name"
              build-status: "$.detail.build-status"
              deep-link: "$.detail.additional-information.logs.deep-link"
            InputTemplate: |
              "Build '<build-id>' for build project '<project-name>' has reached the build status of '<build-status>'."
Outputs:
  QueueName:
    Description: Name of the SNS Topic we created
    Value:
      Fn::GetAtt:
      - SNSTopic
      - TopicName
  TopicARN:
    Description: ARN of the SNS Topic we created
    Value:
      Ref: SNSTopic
```

Can anyone please help on this ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you verify that your event is fired at all?

Comment: Im searching to find how to verify the event is fired or not.

Comment: It is triggered, I could see it in Cloudwatch Graphed Metrics level. It shows as failed builds

Comment: If you manually in console subscribe an sns topic, does it work? Namely, can you make it work manually with the same rule?

Comment: Manually it worked fine, i have received notification mail as well. The code you have updated with TopicPolicy seems like a json format, that won't be an issue right ?

Comment: If it manually works, check sns topic policy autogenerated by aws and compare with the template. I think policy is fine. This is what I use in my templates.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233613/discussion-between-kivi-and-marcin).

Comment: Sorry, can't chat now

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. Let me check the template and the possibilities.